# how to close the menu with a Click outside in jquery on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I got a menu that opens correctly and close correctly when you touch the menu on  a iPad. thats fine, but i also want to close the menu, when you touch outside the menu. it works when you touch a picture and a link, but it doesnt work when you touch anywhere else.

here its my code:

HTML :

```
<nav onclick="" class="acconicon">

<nav class="accon">


 <figure class="acmlogo"></figure>


<h5 class="acconh5">Hovedmenu</h5>      
<ul class="sbm3">
    <a href="index.php"><li class="acfront">Forside </li></a>
    <a href="news.php"><li class="acnews">Nyheder </li></a>
    <a href="artists.php"><li class="acartists">Artister</li></a>
    <a href="releases.php"><li class="acreleases">Udgivelser</li></a>
    <a href="live.php"><li class="aclive">Live</li></a>
    <a href="video.php"><li class="acvideo">Videoer </li></a>
    <a href="interaction.php"><li class="accomp">Konkurrencer</li></a>
    <a href="remix.php"><li class="acremix">Remix</li></a>
</ul>


</nav>

</nav>
```

Script:

```
    $('html').click(function() {
   $('.accon').hide(); 
});

$('.acconicon').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.acconicon').click(function(event){
     $('.accon').toggle();
});
```

Comment: im a newbie, how do i use onblur?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use not selector of `JQuery`. I created a simple code that you should try.

```
$('*:not(.acconh5,sbm3,sbm3 > a)').click(function() {
    $('.accon').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: thx for the quick answer, but it didnt work :-(! the result was after I used your code was you couldnt open the menu at all..

Comment: The selector of my code only it's for close the menu and obiously you can't open it when this function is runnig, you must at to the not selector the elment that you use for open the menu else that element will close the menu to.

Comment: like deleting my own jquery-code? and what about the empty onclick="" ?

Comment: Sry if it's hard to understand I will try to explain it better.
`*` in the JQuery selector is for select all elements, and the `:not()` it's for adding elements exceptions. In the not selector I only at the elements of the menu and that will result that if you click to any element of menu that will not hide but if you click any other element of the html, menu will hide. Therefore if the menu is hide with that selector never will be show becouse you must at the element that use for show it at the not exception selector

Comment: i dont understand that :S . i rather hear what should  I do, than try to understand it :)

Comment: At the id or class of the element that you use for open the menu into the not selector.
Like that if is an id: `$('*:not(.acconh5,sbm3,sbm3 > a,#element_open_menu)')`
and like that if is a class `$('*:not(.acconh5,sbm3,sbm3 > a,.element_open_menu)')`

Comment: I just have solutions around not() selector for your problem, the better way for use it is to put to all elements you want to avoid the hide event a class like `not_hide` and then use the selector that way, `$('*:not(.not_hide)')` and that's the last solution i have in mind for you'r problem sry :(.